# How do I remove "undefined" from the first iteration in my for loop of an array?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

As long as index is bigger than or equal to 0, iterate console.log().
However, when I run this code, I always end up with an undefined at the end. How do I write the code so this does not happen?

```
let array = ["Fiji", "Santorini", "Bora Bora", "Vancouver"];
let arrayLength = array.length;

for(let index = arrayLength; index => 0; index = index - 1)
{
    console.log(array[index]);
}
```

This fixed it:

---

let arrayLength = array.length - 1

index => 0;

Comment: `index >= 0` not `index => 0`

Comment: I really wonder if anybody pointed out the possibility of this exact point of confusion at the language committee meetings.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not sure if you're insulting me or educating me.

Comment: I still need to remove the first iteration of the "undefined". Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it. Never mind.

Comment: Luka no that second comment was really just a comment. Recently (a couple years ago) `=>`, which used to be a syntax error, became something to create a new type of function. `index => 0` is interpreted now as a function, so the loop never ends (until it gets an error).  It's not your fault :)

Comment: Ah, okey:) To be fair, I should've known. CodeAcademy showed me this a couple of days ago. I just forgot. Thx, anyways!

Answer (score 0):

As @Pointy commented, the "greater equal" operator is `>=` not `=>`. You should also start at `let index = arrayLength-1` since Javascript starts counting from 0, and thus the index of the last item is one less than the length of the array. This should run fine:

```
let array = ["Fiji", "Santorini", "Bora Bora", "Vancouver"];
let arrayLength = array.length;

for(let index = arrayLength-1; index >= 0; index = index - 1)
{
    console.log(array[index]);
}
```

Comment: Actually. It was my understanding that the reason we add array.length - 1 is because the xxxx.length method returns an integer that is +1 greater than the actual length. It says so in the MDN-docs. Here: [link] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length[/link]

Comment: Anyhow. I fixed it right before you replied, but thanks anyways:))

Comment: `xxxx.length method returns an integer that is +1 greater than the actual length` no ... xxxx.length is exactly equal to the length of xxxx - nothing in that documentation states that 1 is added to actual length ... it states `numerically greater than the highest index` ... and since array indicies start at `0` ... an array with 1 element has a maximum index of 0, and a length of 1

Comment: This is the correct answer - a simple misunderstanding of the `>=` operator.  Also, the fact it says `undefined` in the console is irrelevant.  That's simply the return value when executing the code.